# Ireport - JasperServer: PostgreSQL error (Driver)

Tags: postgresql, driver, ireport, jasperserver

I am trying to run my report created on iReport 4 on the jasperserver with a postgresql database (On my localhost).

The report runs perfect on the preview on iReport. Now when I upload it to the jasperServer I get the following error:

> 1 - org.postgresql.Driver 
>   java.lang.Exception: 1 - org.postgresql.Driver 
>   at com.jaspersoft.ireport.jasperserver.ws.WSClient.runReport(WSClient.java:403) 
>   at com.jaspersoft.ireport.jasperserver.ws.WSClient.runReport(WSClient.java:320) 
>   at com.jaspersoft.ireport.jasperserver.ReportRunner.run(ReportRunner.java:70) 
>   at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572) 
>   at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)

Then I checked my OLAP settings on my jasperServer and noticed it doesn't have a postgresql driver.

> mondrian.jdbcDrivers
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver,org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver,oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver,com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

And on my jasperreport I use the following driver:

> PostgreSQL (org.postgresql.Driver)

I think this is the problem. Does anyone know how I can add this postgresql driver to my jasperserver?
Or is there a different problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PostgreSQL driver jar should go into the lib directory of your application server.
If you are using the bundled version of tomcat that comes with jasperServer, this will be

`<jasperServer_install>\apache-tomcat\lib`

More detailed instructions are available [here](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/mwiki/index.php/Jasperserver/DataSources).